C# Web API performance issue when there are multiple concurrent request which internally call AmazonPollyClient APIs
I am working on a product in which customer can come and configure the Amazon Polly TTS config. After that we have exposed one API /generateTTS which accepts 2 input parameters, text and config Id. Using this, we fetch customer's config and build Polly client and then return the response which is returned by Amazon Polly client.
Here we have observed that while executing /generateTTS, we are building the AmazonPollyClient for every request which is causing performance issue.
To resolve this issue I was thinking to hold the AmazonPollyClient client in a static ConcurrentDictionary.
Create AmazonPollyClient for every first request of unique config and then store them in ConcurrentDictionary so that we can use same client for subsequent request.
private static ConcurrentDictionary<string, AmazonPollyClient> _clientCache = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, AmazonPollyClient>();

private void InitClient(int busNo, string configName,string VendorName, PollyTTSConfig pollyTTSConfig)
{
    if (client == null)
    {
        if (validateConfig(pollyTTSConfig))
        {
            string cacheKey = CacheKeyForVoiceList(busNo, configName, VendorName);
            if (!_clientCache.TryGetValue(cacheKey, out client))
            {
                RegionEndpoint regionEndpoint = RegionEndpoint.GetBySystemName(pollyTTSConfig.Region);
                AWSCredentials awsCreds = new BasicAWSCredentials(pollyTTSConfig.AccessKey, pollyTTSConfig.SecretKey);
                client = new AmazonPollyClient(awsCreds, regionEndpoint);
                logClientDetails(pollyTTSConfig);
            }
            else 
            { 
                _logger.LogInformation($"Client found in cache");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            _logger.LogError($"Invalid config");
            throw new Exception("Invalid config");
        }
    }      
}

Will this cause any problems, or is there any other way to resolve the performance issue?

Seems like the correct approach. I would do the persistence of the data in DB preferably because if the application restarts, then the cache is also lost. So collecting the data and saving to a DB and then retrieving it might not cause a big performance hit and would achieve your cache.

I am not caching the data, here we are storing the Third party Amazon Client. Which is used to call third party API

So what is the problem then? Your question is not very clear on your requirement. How are you determining the performance issue?

When we were doing the load testing, it was working fine with 20 RPS, It responded in 1 sec. But as soon as we increase a load to 50 URPS. it starts taking more time 60-70 seconds.

Do you actually investigated which line is causing the performance issue? Find that first

Can you recommend some tool and tutorial which will help me identify the issue on VS enterprise.
